# how to minify a ruby file

Tags: ruby, minify

As we know, there are a lot of tools or library to minify javascript, css, is there any tool or library to minify ruby file? 
 After searching in google, there is no right answer for the question.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure you _want_ to do this?  Ruby code isn't passed over the network in source form like JS and CSS.

Comment: What would be the "right answer"? The only thing accomplished by that would be a minor space savings in most cases. It wouldn't run any faster, even if all non-essential white-space was removed.

Comment: If you want to minify the output that is produced as html, then it is either .html.erb or .haml file. Better convert your .html.erb file to .haml In Production mode the html file will be automatically minified

Comment: Are you really looking to obfuscate your code? You can google that :) but I recommend you don't. The Ruby community benefits greatly from the fact that everyone has access to the source of each others gems etc. Imagine how slowly rails would change if it was closed source!

Comment: JavaScript and CSS allow you to start a new line of code with a semicolon. Without that, the only minification possible would be to reduce indentation and mangle names.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jruby!

When packaging your application into a war or jar you can pass it a `compiled` flag which will compile `.rb` files into java's `.class` bytecode file

[Warbler documentation](https://github.com/jruby/warbler#usage)